# asynchronous loading scene freezes Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

when I press the button, the scene freezes, some time passes, after which the next scene immediately appears

Unity 2020.3.37f1

```
AsyncOperation asyncLoad;

async void LoadScene(int loadScene)
{
    asyncLoad = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(loadScene, LoadSceneMode.Single);
    asyncLoad.allowSceneActivation = false;

    while (!asyncLoad.isDone)
    {
        if (asyncLoad.progress >= 0.9f)
        {
            asyncLoad.allowSceneActivation = true;
        }

        await Task.Yield();
    }


}
public void Load()
{
    LoadScene(3);
}
```

Comment: Does it happen if you use the [official method with coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync.html) ?

Comment: @pixlhero, yes, identical situation

Comment: How did you find out that the scene freezes? And is the method called only once?

Comment: @pixlhero, i wrote in `while (!asyncLoad.isDone)` "Debug.Log(asyncLoad.progress)" and after i called LoadScene() and game freezed, some time passes, after which in Console immediately displayed all messages from Debug like "0.056, 0.145, 0.4, 0.78, 0.9"

Comment: when I wrote "Debug.Log(TtimeSinceLevelLoad)" it showed that nothing freezed, however it didn't

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `LoadSceneAsync` is not perfectly async as discussed [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/scenemanager-loadsceneasync-freezes-animation.509366/) for example. This seems to be [by design](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/async-load-is-not-async) and won't be "fixed".

The best workaround would be to either have a loading screen (so not loading while gameplay is still happening). Or perhaps slicing the scene differently, or maybe use `Instantiate` with prefabs.